# Copy two similar structures in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I want to copy two similar structures in C++. Consider the below three structures.

```
struct Dest_Bio
{
       int age;
       char name;
};

struct Source_Bio
{
       int age;
       char name;
};

struct Details
{
       int id;
       Dest_Bio* st_bio; //Needs to be populated with values from Source_Bio
};
```

- I have values filled in 'Source_Bio' structure
- I want to copy these values in Source_Bio into st_bio in 'Details' structure.
- I do not want to create a member for Dest_Bio

I tried the following. It compiles fine but crashes the program on run time.

```
Source_Bio st_ob;
st_ob.age = 5;
st_ob.name = 't';    
Details st_a;
st_a.id = 1;
st_a.st_bio = (Dest_Bio*) malloc(sizeof(Dest_Bio));
memcpy((struct Dest_Bio*)&st_a.st_bio, (struct Source_Bio*)&st_ob,sizeof(Dest_Bio));
```

How can I get this done? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `memcpy` is to the address of `st_a.st_bio` but that's already a pointer. Take out the `&`.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I work with daily on a large C source code base from which several applications are generated.  And it is a constant source of problems with changes and updates.  This appears to be a chopped up example from which there seems to be no reason for why you are wanting to bend C++ into C so I am curious as to why you are doing this.

Comment: Instead of `Source_Bio` and `Dest_Bio` you should probably just have `Bio` and whether an instance of the class is source or dest is contextual based on your code.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way would probably be something like this:

```
struct Dest_Bio { 
    int age;
    char name; // should this really be a string instead of a single char?

    Dest_Bio(Source_Bio const &s) : age(s.age), name(s.name) {}
};

Details st_a;

st_a.id = 1;
st_a.st_bio = new Dest_Bio(st_ob);
```

Better still, you should probably just eliminate `Dest_Bio` and `Source_Bio` and replace both with just `Bio` and be done with it. You also almost certainly want to replace your `Dest_Bio *st_bio` with some sort of smart pointer -- a raw pointer is pretty much asking for trouble. Alternatively, just embed a `Bio` object inside the `Details` object (probably the preferred choice).

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the requirement that both `Bio` types be layout-compatible, make a common type `Bio`. Then do the copy in C++ rather than C:

```
st_a.st_bio = new Bio(st_ob);
```

If they do need to be different types, then you might make `Source_Bio` convertible to `Dest_Bio` via a constructor or conversion operator.

That's assuming you have a genuine reason for your third requirement (that it be a pointer rather than a member). Otherwise, make it a member, fixing the potential memory leak, and simplify the code further:

```
st_a.st_bio = st_ob;
```

If you really want to muck around with C functions, then you want to copy to `st_a.st_bio`, not to `&st_a.st_bio` (i.e. overwriting the object, not the pointer to it). Only do that if you hate whoever will be maintaining the code.